# What do these symbols mean in Season 2 of The Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

In the second season of The Witcher each episode has a symbol what does these symbols represent?

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: They symbolise things that happen in the episode/series or things we see in them.

Comment: Asked and answered here for the first season; https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105780/what-are-the-different-symbols-in-the-witcher-tv-series-intro

Comment: [Behind The Witcher Season 2 episode titles and logos](https://redanianintelligence.com/2021/12/07/behind-the-witcher-season-2s-episode-titles-and-logos/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: as with the nature of explaining the symbols there is going to be a lot of spoilers and they are unmarked. Read at your own risk.

#### 1. A Grain of Truth

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This symbol shows a hooded winged creature. Undoubtedly this is referring to Vereena, the bruxa that features with Nivellen as a major part of episode involving Geralt and Ciri. The wings/claws refer to her being a bruxa (a type of vampire) and the hooded part because Nivellen keeps her hidden and tells the two that she's a cat.

Similarly, in the story it was adapted from with the same name in *The Last Wish* Nivellen tells Geralt that Vereena is rusalka to hide her true nature from him.

#### 2. Kaer Morhen

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This symbol shows a Witcher's medallion, which looks to be the one belonging to Eskel. In the episode Eskel is infected by a Leshy and eventually all but turns into one before being killed. The roots sprouting from the Witcher medallion in the logo symbolise this.

[image: View of Eskel's upper half with his medallion hanging from his neck]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### 3. What is Lost

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

I'm not really overly sure what this symbol is referring to. In the books the Swallow is Ciri's symbol though that's yet to be shown in the Netflix series. We do have a large focus on Ciri's training here and how she keeps getting knocked down and powers through to better herself. We also see her focusing on her power a bit more to hunt down the Leshy.

The title of the episode though presumably focuses on a few other things. Yennefer has lost her powers and we see Tiss spot this. We also see those at Aretuza having a memorial for the sorceresses that were lost in the Battle of Sodden. And of course at Kaer Morhen there is some focus on losing Eskel to the Leshy and putting him to rest.

#### 4. Redanian Intelligence

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

The symbol being a cloak and dagger along with the title are referring to Sigismund Dijkstra the head of the Redanian Intelligence. He is introduced in this episode and promptly sets about doing spy stuff.

We also meet the Sandpiper who turns out to be Jaskier who is doing cloak and dagger actions as well.

It's also worth noting that the dagger looks like the one that Voleth Meir used to kill Klef before the other Witchers imprisoned her. I'm not sure what this means other than her constant presence in the background in this episode.

#### 5. Turn Your Back

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Again I'm not quite sure what this refers to in this particular episode. However, a major theme in this season is that everything should be in balance and it's hard to keep it that way. Towards the end of the episode this tips out of favour with a monster coming through a portal in the monolith at Cintra.

#### 6. Dear Friend

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This symbol shows a hand turning into flames and is clearly referring to Rience who is quite the accomplished fire mage and causes quite a stir in this episode. First he attacks Vesemir and Triss in Kaer Morhen and then Geralt, Yennefer and Ciri at the Temple of Melitele.

#### 7. Voleth Meir

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This shows a skull, blindfolded and mouth open, and appears to reference Voleth Meir herself. The episode is pretty heavily focused on her behind the scene and ends with her being set loose.

#### 8. Family

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This episode is focused quite heavily around family, losing and gaining, so the title is pretty apt. The symbol appears to be the Medallion Tree at Kaer Morhen which plays a pretty pivotal role when Voleth Meir cracks it in half revealing a monolith underneath. Pretty much the whole episode involving Geralt and Ciri takes place at the base of the tree.

Comment: "In the books the Swallow is Ciri's symbol though that's yet to be shown in the Netflix series." It sure was in 1st season. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105780/what-are-the-different-symbols-in-the-witcher-tv-series-intro

Comment: @Mithoron I meant in the episodes themselves not out of universe information like episode titles and symbols like those.

Comment: Isn't there somewhere in season 1 where Ciri is referred to as Zireael - maybe by the dryads? Zireael being the elven version of her name, meaning swallow. I don't recall anyone making that association in the books before Avallac'h though.

Comment: @Amarth If you find reference to this that would surely help the answer. I can't remember the moment off the top of my head though and it's been a while since I watched a lot of S1.

Comment: Transcripts of season 1 can be found here. https://8flix.com/transcripts/the-witcher/season-1-5180504/tt5180504s1-dialogue/ I searched for "Zir" in all episodes but didn't find any. I also just noted that the swallow symbol is present in the main logo for the show as well.